# Flask mongoengine pagination

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a small Flask app which renders blog posts:

**views.py:**

```
class ListView(MethodView):

    def get(self, page=1):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render_template('posts/list.html', posts=posts)
```

This is all good, but I would like to add pagination to the `posts` object. Looking at the [project docs](https://github.com/sbook/flask-mongoengine), I see there is a pagination class.

So I tried this:

```
class ListView(MethodView):

    def get(self, page=1):
        posts = Post.objects.paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
        return render_template('posts/list.html', posts=posts)
```

But now I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable
```

So how do I iterate through my `posts` in the template?

Comment: What is your template code ? Can you share ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Pagination` object has an [`items` list](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/pagination.py#L30) which will contain the mongoengine document objects (in your case the `Post` objects). This list can be iterated through to display the documents.

For example, in your template:

```
{% for post in posts.items %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

To get the actual page numbers for pagination links, use [`iter_pages()`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/pagination.py#L83):

```
<div id="pagination-links">
    {% for page in posts.iter_pages() %}
        {{ page }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Both the [documentation](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-queryset) and the [github link above](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/pagination.py#L83), have a better example for pagination links:

```
{% macro render_pagination(pagination, endpoint) %}
    <div class=pagination>
        {%- for page in pagination.iter_pages() %}
            {% if page %}
                {% if page != pagination.page %}
                    <a href="{{ url_for(endpoint, page=page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <strong>{{ page }}</strong>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                <span class=ellipsis>…</span>
            {% endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: updated github links to reflect latest flask-mongoengine release